# Transfer highlights in side-loaded book from Kindle to Android

Tags: kindle, kindle-paperwhite, annotations

I have a side-loaded book on my Kindle and make highlights in it while reading.

Is it possible to transfer the highlights to my Android so that they appear in the same places in the book when opened on android be it in the Android kindle app or a 3rd party app?

I was able to make the Kindle Android app read the side-loaded book, but when I copy the folder with the metadata to the Android the app doesn't pick it up.

It would be fine for me if it was possible to open this with a 3rd party Android app, just that the highlights appear in the book.

I know there's the TXT file but it takes the highlights out of context.